# HighChart marker highlight / tooltip issue, highlight marker does not move

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, jsfiddle

When I move my mouse over the chart I expect the marker to move and the tool tip to appear and highlight each point. But, it just stays on the start. If I move the mouse left and right on the start point it highlights the first and the last point?

Any ideas how to fix this so it highlight correctly over each point?

```
    $(function() {
    var chart;
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: "renderChart",
                    type: 'line'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'
                },
                series: [{
                    data: [[1317772800000, 1087.5], [1317686400000, 1087.5], [1317600000000, 1087.5], [1317340800000, 1087.5], [1317254400000, 1087.5], [1317168000000, 1087.5], [1317081600000, 1087.5], [1316995200000, 1100], [1316736000000, 1100], [1316649600000, 1100], [1316563200000, 1100], [1316476800000, 1100], [1316390400000, 1100], [1316131200000, 1100], [1316044800000, 1100], [1315958400000, 1100], [1315872000000, 1100], [1315785600000, 1100], [1315526400000, 1125], [1315440000000, 1125]]
                }]
            });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WAH8G/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please sort your time-based data into ascending chronological order. That should solve it.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed that. I was bemused at the chart was order in chronological order.